# iOS 8 no longer writes / reads to the settings bundle

Tags: ios8, settings.bundle

Recently updated to Xcode 6.0.1

I have found a few iOS bugs but I am unsure this is a bug or I am misunderstanding how settings bundle should work (given that my code has been working fine in iOS7)

Create a brand new vanilla app and add the default settings bundle, changing nothing.

Run the app choosing iPad 2 as the device.

Goto Home -> Settings and find and click the settings for this app. On the right are 3 default controls. A text entry, switch and slider.

Set all 3 controls to something different to what they are currently.

Either click a different setting on the left or goto Home and back into settings, either way the changes are lost!

So is this a bug or should it lose what you have set these settings to?

Ultimately what this means is that I cannot read back in any settings that are changed by the user in applicationWillEnterForeground.

TIA.

Comment: I can't really help you but i'm curious about this "TIA", what does it mean. This is Apple?
Edit : " Thanks in Advance ". Alright.

Comment: Settings bundle has just stopped writing to NSUserDefaults for all iOS8 devices. Thought this was just a beta bug?

Comment: Have the same problem, any update on this? I can't believe there are so few people affected if this was a general iOS8 bug, we must do something wrong but I cannot figure out what since the exact same valid code was working fine on iOS7 and below

Comment: Has this been fixed yet?

Comment: Yes it was fixed in an ios update